# redHat distro need MySQL module for php5

Tags: command-line-interface, amazon-web-services

I am on `AWS` using `RDS` for my dataBase.  Even though I dont need mySql on my `EC2` instance I cant seem to connect to `RDS` without a `MySql module`

I have tried this `sudo yum install php5-mysql`
but it gives me an error `No package php5-mysql available`

**question:**
any suggestions how to get MySQL module for php5? i dont need the entire server

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

or search with

```
sudo yum search mysql
```